# Mapping one to many relationship to existing database views without keys

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I need to create one to many relationship between two classes.Database do not contains primary or foreign keys. So i decided to create 2 views instead of 3 tables, and views also has no primary/foreign key (Changing the database schema is not allowed)

[Views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zy12k.png)

```
[Table("Barcode")]
public partial class Barcode
{
    [Column("_Barcode")]
    public string _Barcode { get; set; }

    [Column("_SkuRef")]
    [MaxLength(16)]
    public byte[] _SkuRef { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("Id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string _SkuId { get; set; }
}


[Table("SKU")]
public partial class SKU
{
    [Column("_Code", Order = 0)]
    [StringLength(11)]
    public string _Code { get; set; }

    [Column("_Description", Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string _Description { get; set; }

    [Column("_ProductId", Order = 2)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string _ProductId { get; set; }

    [Column("_Ref", Order = 3)]
    [MaxLength(16)]
    public byte[] _Ref { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 4)]
    [StringLength(36)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

In this way, i tryed to use something like

```
using (SkuContext db = new SkuContext())
        {

            var Skutable = db.SKUs;
            foreach(var s in Skutable)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(s.Id);
            }
        }
```

And its working well. But when im trying to add

```
 public partial class Barcode
 {
  ....
    [ForeignKey("_SkuId")]
    [Column("_SkuId")]
    [StringLength(36)]
    public string _SkuId { get; set; }
 }
 public partial class SKU
 {
  ....
    public IEnumerable<Barcode> Barcodes;
 }
```

I'm facing
"The property '_SkuId' cannot be configured as a navigation property" error.
And my question is how to do the right thing? How to create relationship between two classes like these ?

Comment: The biggest issue you have is this "Database do not contains primary or foreign keys." No amount of good code can make up for a poor database design.

Comment: So you need to do changes in the system but you are not allowed to make changes ?

Comment: I dont need to do changes in the system, all i need is just to make some select.

Answer (score 0):

You got error because your table does not contains foreign key. The foreign key attribute will not help cause you don't have such relationship in database.

If you are using ORM, such as Entity Framework, the solution will be to write a stored procedure and to make EF to work with it.

Another way is to implement your own business logic using classes from  `System.Data.SqlClient` by specific reading, writing, etc..

So I consider that such an exercise does not needed in your simple situation. But if you are going just in this straight way, without changing tables, be ready for tons of documentation.

Comment: So instead of this way i decided to do smth different:

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a one-to-many relationship between your `SKU` and `Barcode` views where one SKU has many Barcodes in the same way you would do it if it were tables. Use Fluent API to configure a one-to-many relationship between SKU and Barcode:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    // one-to-many relationship
    // _SkuId foreign key in Barcode
    modelBuilder.Entity<Barcode>()
        .HasRequired(c => c.SKU)
        .WithMany(t => t.Barcodes)
        .Map(m => m.MapKey("_SkuId"));

}
```

Update your classes like the following:

```
[Table("Barcode")]
public partial class Barcode
{
    [Column("_Barcode")]
    public string _Barcode { get; set; }

    [Column("_SkuRef")]
    [MaxLength(16)]
    public byte[] _SkuRef { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("Id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    // need to comment this out
    //[Column("_SkuId")]
    //[StringLength(36)]
    //public string _SkuId { get; set; }


    public virtual SKU SKU { get; set; }
}

[Table("SKU")]
public partial class SKU
{
    [Column("_Code", Order = 0)]
    [StringLength(11)]
    public string _Code { get; set; }

    [Column("_Description", Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string _Description { get; set; }

    [Column("_ProductId", Order = 2)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string _ProductId { get; set; }

    [Column("_Ref", Order = 3)]
    [MaxLength(16)]
    public byte[] _Ref { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 4)]
    [StringLength(36)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Barcode> Barcodes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Additional information: The expression 't => t.Barcodes' is not a valid property expression. The expression should represent a property: C#: 't => t.MyProperty'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) t.MyProperty'.

Comment: I got the same error and found the issue. I guess that's what I get for not testing the code beforehand. Change `public virtual ICollection<Barcode> Barcodes;` to `public ICollection<Barcode> Barcodes { get; set; }`. That will get rid of that error. However, you need to do 1 more thing or you will get another error. Comment out `public string _SkuId { get; set; }` property from `Barcode` partial class. You don't need it since `OnModelCreating` method sets `_SkuId` as the foreign key. I will update my answer.