# Entity framework. How to right map tables without primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

[I tried to solve this problem, but couldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40220572/mapping-one-to-many-relationship-to-existing-database-views-without-keys) so I'm trying to do it another way.

I have a view that consist of 3 tables without any primary/foreign keys.

VS2015 generated this class:

```
[Table("SkuBarcodesView")]
public partial class SkuBarcodesView
{
    [Key]
    [Column("_Code", Order = 0)]
    [StringLength(11)]
    public string C_Code { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("_Description", Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string C_Description { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("_ProductCode", Order = 2)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string C_ProductCode { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("_Ref", Order = 4)]
    [StringLength(36)]
    public string C_Ref { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("_Barcode", Order = 5)]
    public string C_Barcode { get; set; }
}
```

This entity represents sku-barcode table so I may have row's like these:

```
 Product  | Barcode
 -------- | --------
 product0 | barcode0
 product1 | barcode1 
 product2 | barcode2
 product2 | barcode2
```

Now, I need to group it somehow. I'm trying:

```
using (skumodel db = new skumodel())
{
    var query = db.SkuBarcodesViews.GroupBy(e => e.C_Ref)
        .Select(g => new { Barcode = g.C_Barcode });
}
```

But, then I see this error:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>
> Error  CS1061  'IGrouping' does not contain a definition for 'C_Barcode' and no extension method 'C_Barcode' accepting a first argument of type 'IGrouping' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**How can I solve this?**

This is just a start; there are a lot of other tables in the database without keys/foreign keys that I want to work with through EF.

**What is the right way to get data from tables without keys?** How to map tables like these?

Comment: If your view don't have the primary keys, why do you use `[Key]` attribute?

Comment: Class has been generated automatically by ado.net model. Btw i can use field _ref like a key, because without any key attribute i get EntityType 'SkuBarcodesView' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

Comment: It is not Code First if you're using existing database.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is not a primary/foreign keys problem per se. LINQ grouping works not like usual SQL grouping, but more like a `Dictionary`. For your example, group with key `product2` will have two values `barcode2` for each occurence in the table. As we operate with objects in C#, each row is represented by `SkuBarcodesView` instance, so you need something like this if you want to get all the barcodes for the product:

```
using (skumodel db = new skumodel())
{
    var query = db.SkuBarcodesViews.GroupBy(e => e.C_Ref)
        .Select(g => new { 
                             Product = g.Key,
                             Barcodes = g.Select(x => x.C_Barcode) 
               });
}
```

Note, that for now there are no restrictions on the values in your table, so one product may have a lot of different barcodes or a lot of same barcodes etc. How would you tell which one is the right one? Of course, if you're sure there's only similar barcodes, you can do `g.First().C_Barcode` instead of the inner `g.Select()` in the above code to get single barcode.

Second, using `GroupBy()` here is an overkill, you can just use something like:

```
using (skumodel db = new skumodel())
{
    var query = db.SkuBarcodesViews
        .Select(x => new { Ref = x.C_Ref, Barcode = x.C_Barcode })
        .Distinct();
}
```